# GLUT displays just a blank window

Tags: c, glut

Whatever I do, when I open the app, it always displays a blank window.

My display function:

```c
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    
    frame++;
    
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    
    for (float xpos; xpos < 1.0f; xpos = xpos + 0.1f) {
        for (float ypos; ypos < 1.0f; ypos = ypos + 0.1f) {
            glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
                glVertex2f(xpos-0.075f,ypos-0.075f);
                glVertex2f(xpos,ypos-0.075f);
                glVertex2f(xpos,ypos);
                glVertex2f(xpos-0.075f,ypos);
            glEnd();
        }
    }
    
    glutSwapBuffers(); // Required to copy color buffer onto the screen.
    glFlush();
}
```

Does anybody know what's causing the problem?

Comment: For one thing, you don't initialize xpos and ypos, so they start the loops with unknown values.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and describe the difference to the GlutHelloWorld or the tutorial example code which worked for you.